# SQLite from custom path

Tags: javascript, sqlite, xpcom, xulrunner

How can I select an SQLite DB from a custom path using XPCOM? I could already select the db and process it when it is inside the paths like `ProfD` or `HomeDesk` but I need to access it by its absolute file path.

Answer (score 0):

See [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Storage#Opening_a_connection), you merely need to change the file in the example. If you want to access a file by its absolute path then instead of using `FileUtils.getFile()` you should use [`FileUtils.File` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript_code_modules/FileUtils.jsm#The_File_constructor):

```
var file = new FileUtils.File("c:\\foo\\bar");
```